Cypress Component You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
I followed https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/tree/master/examples/ct-webpack-react-ts added Cypress Cucumber for Component tests
Normal Feature test steps like cy.log,cy.wait works fine . But when I try mount , I am getting error "> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders


|   
| 
Package.json:
devdepencies:
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^21.0.3",
"@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
"@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^6.0.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-inlinesvg": "^2.0.1",
"react-refresh-typescript": "^2.0.9",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
"style-loader": "^1.2.1",
"svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.2",
"ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
"typescript": "^5.5.2",
"webpack": "^5.92.1",
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
"webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import * as Webpack from "webpack";
import { devServer } from "@cypress/webpack-dev-server";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import webpack from "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor";

const webpackConfig = (
  cypressConfig: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions,
): Webpack.Configuration => {
  return {
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: [/node_modules/],
          use: [
            {
              loader: "ts-loader",
              options: { transpileOnly: true },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.feature$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/webpack",
              options: cypressConfig,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    devServer(devServerConfig) {
      return devServer({
        ...devServerConfig,
        framework: "react",
        webpackConfig: webpackConfig(devServerConfig.cypressConfig),
      });
    },
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more.
      const options = {
        webpackOptions: require("./webpack.config.js"),
        watchOptions: {},
    };

      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
on("file:preprocessor", webpack(options));
            return config;
      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;
    },
  },
});

App.tsx - step definition
import { When, Then, Given } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import { mount } from "cypress/react18"


Given("Mount App component", () => {
    cy.wait(1000);
    const store =  createStoreForTests({});
    props = {
    x:x
    y:y
    };
    cy.mount(<>
                <h1>App</h1>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <App {...props} />
                </Provider></>
     );
    mount(<App  {...props} />);

});

